# How to create a virtual environment with github actions that can be used by other jobs at the same yaml file?

Tags: github-actions, python-venv

I'm trying to create python venv, but it's "dead" when the job is finished, and I want to use the venv in other jobs. What should I do?

I thought of using cache, but I'm not familiar enough with this option.

Comment: Each job is run in a different runner. `venv` created in one job won't be accessible in another. Even `venv` activated in one step won't be accessible in the next one because each step is run in a different shell. What is your complete use case? Please include your relevant workflow in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can [use workflow artifacts to carry data from one job to the next](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts).

```
      - name: Archive code coverage results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: venv
          path: .venv
```

Then make sure the future jobs declare a `needs:` on the job that created the artifact.

And download it again with download-artifact:

```
- name: Download a single artifact
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
  with:
    name: venv
```